# How to keep focus on the Window opend using "window.Open" after the Page Load of the Parent Page?

Tags: asp.net

I am working on an application. I have opened a Window using

```
  window.open()
```

Now after opening this window, the parent Page is getting Refreshed(Means Page Load is Happening).

Now , How can I set the Focus on the Child Window after the Page load of the Parent Page.
Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

To set the focus on new window.

Try Using

`window.focus()`

Comment: Thanks for Your Help. But I have used Window.Focus(). Its focusiing on that child window, but after the Parent Page is Reloading, then the Focus is coming on the Parent Page and the Child Window is getting Minimized.. Please Help..

Answer (score 0):

Get the handle to the window you are opening, and set focus to it using the handle after you are done reloading the parent page.

```
var popup = window.open(); //open the child window
location.reload(); // reload the parent page
popup.focus();  //set focus on the child window
```